# $A$ is the set of all $n \times n$ matrices where $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$, is $A$ a subspace of $M_{nn}$ (where $n\ge2$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$For $A =$ zero matrix,
$$W=\{ A \in M_{nn} : \tr(A) = 0 \}$$
I can proof that the set of all n x n matrices A with $\tr(A)=0$ is a subset of $M_{nn} $for$ \ n \geq 2$

Since $A=0$ the set is clearly non-empty

Closed under addition:
$$
\tr(A + B)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (A + B)_{ii} =\sum_{i=1}^{n} (A)_{ii} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} (B)_{ii} = 0 + 0 = 0
$$
so,$$
A + B \in W
$$

Closed under scalar multiplication ($k \in R$):
$$
\tr(kA)=\sum_{i=1}^n (kA)_{ii} =k \sum_{i=1}^n (A)_{ii} =k(0) = 0
$$
so,
$$
kA \in W
$$
But how do I proof for the cases where A is not the zero vector but $\tr(A)= 0$, or is it unnecessary to confirm this for the other cases?

Comment: I think you mean to ask whether the set $A$ is a *vector subspace* of $M_{n \times n}$. Also, you seem to be using $A$ to denote both the set at hand and some of its elements (sometimes arbitrary ones, sometimes not)---at best this is unnecessarily confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$What you did is exactly what you  are searching for , but let me agian organize and clarify your idea.

Let $\mathfrak{A}=\{ A \in M_{n \times n } \mid  tr(A)= 0\} $, with $n \geq 2$.

Closed under addition: Let  $A, B \in \mathfrak{A} $, then  $ tr(A)=tr(B)=0$. On the other hand 
$$
\tr(A + B)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (A + B)_{ii} =\sum_{i=1}^{n} (A)_{ii} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} (B)_{ii} = 0 + 0 = 0
$$
so,$$
A + B \in \mathfrak{A}
$$

Closed under scalar multiplication ($k \in \mathbb{R}$):
$$
\tr(kA)=\sum_{i=1}^n (kA)_{ii} =k \sum_{i=1}^n (A)_{ii} =k(0) = 0
$$
so,
$$
kA \in \mathfrak{A}
$$
Thus $\mathfrak{A} $ is vector subspace of  $ M_{n\times n }$.